# How can I populate the content of a Word template using Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

Currently, I am learning to use Access VBA to populate a Word template. I have only been able to find methods on Google that involve inserting bookmarks in Word to mark the position of the fill-in. However, in the Word template examples I have, the spots needing to be filled in use something like ${...}. Is there a specific syntax in VBA that uses ${...} for marking placeholders?

I have found that many replacement engines use similar syntax, but none of them belong to VBA.

Comment: Take a look at using mail merge and merge fields. This is a Word concept. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-mail-merge-to-send-access-data-to-word-053cc639-fe30-4d3a-943d-0bee0892f16a First try doing it manually in Word and then structure your Access vba to create what you need. Merge fields can be formatted in Word.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42814790/vba-access-find-and-replace-text-in-word-document

Comment: Welcome xiao ly! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: https://davetallett26.github.io/wordvba.html